# Connecting points between missing data in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm using chart.js and I have some missing data between multiple day entries at certain points in my chart. I've assigned these values null, but would like the chart to draw a connection line between the missing points. Here is what I have:

[image]

Is there a way to connect the dots in chart.js? Or perhaps someone could point me towards a chart library that can. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and i've modified [this](http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/sLgefm04/) version like this:

```
                    var lastPoint = null;
                helpers.each(dataset.points, function (point, index) {

                    if (!point.ignore && dataset.skipNullValues && lastPoint) {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);

                        if (this.options.bezierCurve) {
                            ctx.bezierCurveTo(
                                lastPoint.controlPoints.outer.x,
                                lastPoint.controlPoints.outer.y,
                                point.controlPoints.inner.x,
                                point.controlPoints.inner.y,
                                point.x,
                                point.y
                            );
                        } else {
                            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
                        }
                        ctx.stroke();
                    }

                    if (index > 0 && !dataset.points[index - 1].ignore && !point.ignore) {
                        if (this.options.bezierCurve) {
                            ctx.bezierCurveTo(
                                dataset.points[index - 1].controlPoints.outer.x,
                                dataset.points[index - 1].controlPoints.outer.y,
                                point.controlPoints.inner.x,
                                point.controlPoints.inner.y,
                                point.x,
                                point.y
                            );
                        }
                        else {
                            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
                        }

                        lastPoint = point;
                    }
                    else if (index === 0 || !point.ignore) {
                        ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y);

                        if (!point.ignore) {
                            lastPoint = point;
                        }
                    }

                }, this);
```

For a better structure i have set a property for the dataset called "skipNullValues":

```
            var datasetObject = {
                label: dataset.label || null,
                fillColor: dataset.fillColor,
                strokeColor: dataset.strokeColor,
                pointColor: dataset.pointColor,
                pointStrokeColor: dataset.pointStrokeColor,
                tooltip: dataset.tooltip,
                line: dataset.line,
                fill: dataset.fill,
                points: [],
                skipNullValues: dataset.skipNullValues
            };
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s56pu18u/) is the full working version!

Maybe there is a better solution, but for my uses it works.

Let me know if it is working for you!

Comment: Nice! That looks exactly like what I need. I'll work on implementing it.

Comment: This is a great and much needed addition to Chart.js, they should add it to the main codebase. Nice work!

Comment: Do you know if this is functionality is available in Chart JS v2?

Answer (score 83):

New version supports skipping missing data.
You can set spanGaps: true in the options.
Then if you have null or NaN for missing data, it will skip it and connect to the next point.

```
.....
showTooltips: true,
options: {
    spanGaps: true,
    .....
}
.....
```

[Documentation here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties)

Comment: hi, do you know how to change the line to dotted between gaps?

Comment: Hi @Ian, there is an issue open for this: github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5956 The thing is you can actually do dashes for spanGaps but it with a trick. The trick is to provide two copies of the same dataset one with borderDash (chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling) and spanGaps true which will draw the entire chart with dashes and then the same dataset with no borderDash and no spanGaps which will draw a solid line over the dashes except the gap area. So the final result will look like what you want.

Comment: I dont see any spanGaps for bar charts, how would you solve this?

Comment: What would be the value of the fake (spanned) bar in a bar chart? That's very misleading and visually different than making the spans on a line chart.

Answer (score 17):

For charts.js v2, you just define it in the dataset:

```
var data = {
labels: labels,
datasets: [ {
    backgroundColor: "#94b5c244",
    borderColor: "#94b5c2",
    data: data,
    label: "AAPL",
    spanGaps: true
}]
};
```

Comment: just adding spanGaps: true in datasets worked for me.

Comment: hi, do you know how to change the line to dotted between gaps?

Comment: @Ian - dotted lines for spanGaps https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/segments.html

Answer (score 2):

For charts.js v2

Use the plugin hooks.
The following seems to work pretty well for data returning null. It will draw the line with out the point. It connect points though null values.

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
        beforeDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
            for (dataset of chart.config.data.datasets) {
                for(data of dataset._meta[chart.id].data) {
                    data._model.skip = false;
                    data._model.tension = 0;
                }
            } 
        }
    });
```

I am not too exited about a double for loop. This can possibly be more efficient. Perhaps there is also more proper hooks to use. However, this should do what you need.

See
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/09-Advanced.md

Comment: This plugin will override the settings (tension) of all charts.