# Javascript: How to graph only certain values

Tags: javascript, arrays, graphing, chart.js

For the following code, how would I get rid of the value for May, but keep the graph going from April to June without May dropping down to zero?:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/sLgefm04/6/

```
 var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, null, null, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
```

Comment: Can't quite figure out what you mean. Replace "May" with ""?

Comment: It looks like you are asking about something that is similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107847/connecting-points-between-missing-data-in-chart-js

Comment: set the May value to null.

Comment: So let's say I have no data for "May", but I dont want the graph to discontinue. I just want the slope to go through "May". Null wont work

Comment: I don't see any other solution except setting for May the value of the average of April and June. Does this suit you in your case ?