# How can I make lines fully connected in a multi-line chart even when one dataset is more sparse than another?

Tags: chart.js

I have a multi-line graph with 2 datasets, where one set has data for every label and the other has some missing entries.
[image: Multi-line graph with one sparse data set]

Is there a way to draw the sparse line such that the data points that do exist are connected?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232364/247722

Add the following to the options object:

```
        options: {
             spanGaps: true,
```

I haven't been able to find documentation for this param, however, so not sure how well supported it is.