# Chart.js - Is there a way to always show the line on a line graph? (continuous line)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

For example, if I have a line graph of a single dataset with a single point of data, I would want a solid horizontal line shown at that point, spanning the entire x-axis range, rather than just showing the data point with no line.
Another example, if there were two points, and the second point was higher than the first, the line would start at the left end of the graph (at the same height as the first point), go in a straight horizontal line to the first point, then go from the first point up to the second point (as any line graph would), and then continue in a straight horizontal line (at the height of the second point) all the way to the end of the graph on the right side.

Visual example of what I want to happen with only two data points:
[image of a line graph with continuous line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quk5F.png)

Comment: this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107847/connecting-points-between-missing-data-in-chart-js please make sure you search stackoverflow before asking a new question. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu That seems to be about skipping gaps in data, not making the line continuous from before the start of the data & through after the end of the data. Unless I'm missing something there?
I've already tried spanGaps and it doesn't cover what I need.